# usar un campo TranslatableModel en un formulario

Tags: python, django

Tengo una clase que representa un curso en varios idiomas (django-parler) de la siguiente forma:

```
class Curso(TranslatableModel):
   translations = TranslatedFields(
       nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200),
       observaciones = models.TextField(default=None, null=True,  blank=True)
   )
   fecha_ini = models.DateTimeField('fecha_inicio',  default=None, blank=False)
   fecha_fin = models.DateTimeField('fecha_fin',  default=None, blank=False)
```

Cuando intento crear un formulario con esta clase en forms.py de la siguiente forma:

```
class CursosForm(ModelForm):
     
     class Meta:
         model = Curso

         fields = ['nombre', 'fecha_ini', 'fecha_fin']
```

Me salta un error de que no encuentra el campo nombre

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (nombre) specified for Curso
```

¿Cómo podría utilizar ese campo en el formulario?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución al problema

En el archivo forms.py importamos la siguiente libería

```
from parler.admin import TranslatableModelForm
```

y creamos el formulario a importar

```
class CursosForm(**TranslatableModelForm**):
     
     class Meta:
         model = Curso

         fields = ['nombre', 'fecha_ini', 'fecha_fin','preinscripcion', 'activo', 'ocultar_curso', 'observaciones']
         labels = {
            'nombre': _('nombre'),#campo con idiomas
            'fecha_ini': _('fecha_ini'),
            'fecha_fin': _('fecha_fin'), 
            'preinscripcion': _('preinscripcion'),
            'ocultar_curso': _('ocultar_curso'),
            'activo': _('email'),
            'observaciones': _('observaciones'),#campo con idiomas
        

    }
```